Why is the image of Laplacian of a connected graph precisely all vectors orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}$?
Theorem 2.3 in Vishnoi's monograph on Laplacian solvers is

Let $L$ be the Laplacian of a graph $G=(V,E)$. Then, $\lambda_2(L)>0$ iff $G$ is connected.

Later, it is claimed that,

it follows from Theorem 2.3 that for a connected graph, $\text{Im}(L)$ consists of all vectors orthogonal to the vector $\mathbf{1}$

I don't see how this immediately follows. Can someone point out the connection?

Note that we have from elementary linear algebra the relation $\text{Im}(A) = \text{ker}(A^T)^\perp$ for any matrix $A$. Here:

$\ker(A)$ is the nullspace or kernel of $A$
$A^T$ is the transpose
$(\cdot)^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement of a subspace: For a subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, we define $V^\perp = \{w \in \mathbb{R}^n : \forall v \in V, w \cdot v = 0\}$, the set of all vectors orthogonal to $V$.

But the Laplacian is symmetric by its definition, so $L^T = L$.
As $\lambda_2(L) > 0$ in the connected case, we know that there is exactly one zero eigenvalue, so the kernel of $L$ is spanned by $\mathbf{1}$, the eigenvector of $\lambda_1(L)=0$.
So $\text{Im}(L) = (\ker L^T)^\perp = (\ker L)^\perp = (\text{span} \{\mathbf{1}\})^\perp$, where the latter is precisely the set described in your question.
